# How can wavefunction degeneracy be incoperated into a tight binding model?

Tags: condensed-matter, tight-binding

Say one wanted to calculate the band structure of the E2u orbital in some molecular crystal, which is the HOMO. How are the two states dealt with in the tight binding hamiltonian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two states are dealt by introducing orbital degrees of freedom in the tight binding Hamiltonian, s.t.

$$H=-\sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta,\sigma}t_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}c_{i\alpha\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\beta\sigma}+h.c.,$$

where $i,j$ label the sites, $\alpha,\beta$ label the $E_{2u}$ orbitals, and $\sigma$ label the spin.